# How to iterate over grouped LINQ data in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two tables. One table is called Occurrence that contains the following:

```
OccurrenceID | EmployeeID | OccurrenceDate | Points | Comment
-------------------------------------------------------------
1            |1           |2012-01-01      |5       |yada    
2            |1           |2012-02-01      |3       |blah    
3            |2           |2012-03-01      |2       |yada
```

The other table is called Employee and contains the following:

```
EmployeeID | EmployeeName
-------------------------
 1         |Jack
 2         |Jill
```

I am trying to group these two tables together and end up with a single line for each employee that will show the total points in a view in my MVC 4 project. So for the above example my output should be:

```
Name    | Points
----------------
Jack    |8
Jill    |2
```

Here is the LINQ query that I've tried in my Controller:

```
        var groupedOccurrences = from o in db.Occurrences.Include(o => o.Employee)
                                 where o.OccurrenceDate >= beginDate
                                    && o.OccurrenceDate <= endDate
                                 group o by new {o.EmployeeID, o.Points} into g
                                 select new {
                                     Name = g.Key.EmployeeID,
                                     Total = g.Sum(o => o.Points)
                                 };

        return View(groupedOccurrences);
```

And here is my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<PtoTracker.Occurrence>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Employee
        </th>
        <th>
            Total Pts.
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Employee.EmployeeName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Points)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

When I navigate to this view I get this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PtoTracker.Occurrence]'.

Can someone help me understand what I should be doing differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to new up instances of your view expected class

```
var groupedOccurrences = 
   (from o in db.Occurrences.Include(o => o.Employee)
    where o.OccurrenceDate >= beginDate && o.OccurrenceDate <= endDate
    group o by new {o.EmployeeID, o.Points} into g
    select new { Name = g.Key.EmployeeID, Total = g.Sum(o => o.Points)}
   ).AsEnumerable();


var model = groupedOccurrences.Select(item => new PtoTracker.Occurrence { 
                         Name = item.Name,
                         Total = item.Total });
```

your view is expecting `IEnumerable` of `PtoTracker.Occurrence` but you are sending it an `IQuerable` of anonymes type instead.

Comment: That gave me an error that said _The entity or complex type 'PtoTrackerModel.Occurrence' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query._

Comment: @Splendor Use the query you have in the OP, then after it add `AsEnumerable` so that the remainder of the query is evaluated in Linq-to-Objects, then add a `Select` that maps the anonymous object to your `Occurrence` object.

Comment: @Servy Can you help me understand how to add a `Select` that maps the anonymous object to my `Occurrence` object? This is my first MVC project and I'm not sure what that means exactly.

Comment: @Splendor `.Select(item => new Occurrence(){ ... });`